# Parsley JS force Field to fail validate status

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, parsley.js

I'm validating a form using parsley JS. 
When user register on the system, System checks whether his police_id is exists in the system or not.
Here that AJAX Jquery code.

```
//police_id
$('#add_user  input[name=police_id]').keyup(function (e) {
    $('.exists_police_id').hide();
    $('.ok_police_id').hide();
    var site_path = $('#sitePath').val();
    var value =  $(this).val();
    var field = 'policeId';
    var table_name = 'tbl_users';
    if(value.length>9 ){
        $('.loading_pic_police_id').show();
        $.ajax({
            url:site_path +'/users_manage_cont/check_unique_fields',
            method:'POST',
            data:{table_name:table_name,field:field,value:value},

            success:function(data)
            {
                $('.loading_pic_police_id').hide();

                if(data ==''){
                    $('.ok_police_id').show();
                }else{ 
                    $('input[name=police_id]').parsley().addError('forcederror', {message: ' This Police ID already Exists in the System.', updateClass: true});
                    return false; //this validation fails
                }
            }

        });
    }
});
```

If police_id not exists response data is null. Then allow user to submit the form.
But the problem is when police_id exists in the table,The form should be validate=false. 
Here look my else{} part

```
 $('input[name=police_id]').parsley().addError('forcederror', {message: ' This Police ID already Exists in the System.', updateClass: true});
                return false; //this validation fails
```

This set Error message and field color red.
But when click submit button the form can be submitted.
How to make parsley validate status false when there is existing police_id found in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only showing an error message, but you are not actually making the validation fail.

Here's my suggestion:

1. Write the return value from AJAX to a hidden input field
2. Test you police_id input field with parsley to be **not** equal to the value of that hidden field.

I made a jsfiddle. If you enter "12345" (your value of course should come from AJAX) it will give you an error message and not validate. If you enter something else it will validate. It's **not** perfect, but it should give you an impression what i mean.

jsfiddle.net/68y7nc0t/

Regards